# Mac terminal command becomes really slow after "git init"

Tags: git, macos, terminal

I typed `git init` in my project directory and then commands slow down on every directory. I tried removing the `.git` directory but it didn't work. Changing zsh to bash made the terminal normal. How to fix that?

Comment: do you have any framework like ohmyzsh or zpresto with a git plugin enabled?

Comment: Yes I have that

Comment: Try running it in a shell without those plugins enabled.

Comment: In that case, this might help you find where the problem is http://sangsoonam.github.io/2019/08/05/why-zsh-is-slow-for-git-repos.html